# How to create new template in Cornerstone theme using stencil framework

Tags: bigcommerce, cornerstone, stencils

I am new to Bigcommerce, I need to create a page template in my Bigcommerce theme (Cornerstone).

I have followed the documentation but its redirected to 404 page. Please help me in this.

I have also tried with the below link but the Url redirected to 404 page
[Creating a custom page template in stencil for bigcommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024403/creating-a-custom-page-template-in-stencil-for-bigcommerce?rq=1)

Note : I have installed stencil framework in local environment and trying it

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/template-files/custom-templates/about-custom-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common cause for 404 errors when working with custom templates locally is that the page the custom template has been mapped to isn't a page that exists in the live store. For example, if you map "custom-product.html":"/my-product/" in your .stencil file, you'll need to have created a product page in your live store with the URL /my-product/. The template needs to map to a live page of the same type: if you're creating a webpage, you'll need to map to a real webpage; if you're creating a category page, you'd map the custom template to one of your existing category URLs. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your time and reply Karen. I have upload and applied the theme in my store but still its showing 404page. Can you explain how to map the locally created file to a live stencil framework?

Comment: Hi John, Yes--if you are no longer working locally and have uploaded the theme to your store, assign the custom template to the page from that page's Edit screen within the control panel. The reason for mapping pages in the .stencil file is only to let you preview the custom template with the page while you're working locally. When you're ready to assign templates to the live store, follow these instructions: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/template-files/custom-templates/assigining-templates-to-pages#assigning_assigning-a-web-page